# SQL Server While loop for last day of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

### I want last day of every month so I wrote query like

```
declare @date datetime set @date='31-jan-2012' 
while @date<='31-Dec-2012' 
  Begin 
    print @date 
    set @date= DATEADD(M,1,@date)
  End
```

### But I got Result like

```
Jan 31 2012 12:00AM
Feb 29 2012 12:00AM
Mar 29 2012 12:00AM
Apr 29 2012 12:00AM
May 29 2012 12:00AM
Jun 29 2012 12:00AM
Jul 29 2012 12:00AM
Aug 29 2012 12:00AM
Sep 29 2012 12:00AM
Oct 29 2012 12:00AM
Nov 29 2012 12:00AM
Dec 29 2012 12:00AM
```

**Please help me**

Comment: do it with 1st and substract one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the things everybody said, here comes the update:

```
Declare @FromDate   DateTime
;

Select  @FromDate   =   Convert(DateTime, '2012-1-1')
;

With    CTE (
    Level
,   FirstDayOfMonth
,   Value
)   As  (
    Select  1       As  Level
    ,   @FromDate
    ,   DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Month, 1, @FromDate))
Union   All
    Select  Level
    +   1
    ,   FirstDayOfMonth
,   DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Month, Level + 1, FirstDayOfMonth))
        From    CTE
        Where   Level   <   12
)   Select  Value
        From    CTE
        Order   By  Value
```

It's a `CTE` (Common Table Expression). The first value should be the first day of the second month, after adding -1 day it will be the last day of January. And of course it will give you the result.

What I did was to just use **DateAdd(Day, -1, [The first day of the next month])**, that simple!

Just for fun, this way, I did start with the first day of the February, and let the engine detects the last day of January! :D Maybe next year after another sandy's cousin storm earth changes its way and January wasn't 31 days anymore! So your code will work then...

Thank you everyone for making me update this answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It suffers exactly the same problem as the OPs question - once it's hit February, the day portion gets fixed to 28 or 29.

Comment: The correct answer is not meant to be a complete script and you just do copy and paste thing. It's something that shows the questioner the point to solve their problem and they should decide about which one is the correct answer I think. by the way I'll update the answer and thank you about mentioning the problem.

Comment: I'm just surprised when someone accepts an answer when it suffers exactly the same problem that they were seeking to solve.

Comment: Maybe he's got an idea about how to solve the problem. I think you should ask himself. :)

Comment: Also it's updated by the time you are reading this comment and thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Mohammad Goudarzi `Convert(DateTime, '2011-2-1')` and `GetDate()` really need to be the same otherwise the first date returned will be out of step with the following 11. So you either need to use `GetDate()` in both cases or use `Convert(DateTime, '2011-2-1')` in both cases. :)

Comment: @DMK I'm so sorry but I didn't get the point. Could you just simplify that?

Comment: @Mohammad Goudarzi Currently the query will return `2011-01-31`,`2013-02-28`,`2013-03-31`. Jumping from 2011 to 2013.

Comment: Wow! I got it. I'm on it. Thanks

Comment: Updated @DMK. Again thank you about telling me I'm wrong. What doesn't kill me makes me stronger! Am I right? ;)

Answer (score 5):

You might be better off with:-

```
declare @date datetime;
declare @lastDay datetime;

-- Start on the first day of the next month
-- This'll ensure that your month add doesn't throw 
-- weird results
set @date='01-Feb-2012'
while @date<='01-Jan-2013'

Begin
    -- Get last day of previous month
    set @lastDay = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date)

    -- print that
    print @lastDay

    -- increment @date to move one month into the future.
    set @date= DATEADD(month,1,@date)
End
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the version of SQL Server you are using.

If you are on `SQL Server 2012`, you can use the [`EOMONTH()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) function.

Comment: mine is SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try:

```
Declare @Month Integer
Set @Month = 1
While @Month <= 12
Begin
  Print DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+@Month,0))
  Set @Month = @Month+1
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below function what you want can be achieved by this query:-

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME SET @StartDate = '2012-01-31'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME SET @EndDate = '2012-12-31'

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.F_TABLE_DATE.END_OF_MONTH_DATE FROM dbo.F_TABLE_DATE(@StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Here is a date function I found many years ago and I still use today, it contains everything to do with dates you could possibly want.

```
create function [dbo].[F_TABLE_DATE]
(
    @FIRST_DATE     datetime,
    @LAST_DATE      datetime
)


returns  @DATE table 
(
[DATE_ID]               [int]       not null 
    primary key clustered,
[DATE]                  [datetime]  not null ,
[NEXT_DAY_DATE]             [datetime]  not null ,
[YEAR]                  [smallint]  not null ,
[YEAR_QUARTER]              [int]   not null ,
[YEAR_MONTH]                [int]       not null ,
[YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR]          [int]       not null ,
[QUARTER]               [tinyint]   not null ,
[MONTH]                 [tinyint]   not null ,
[DAY_OF_YEAR]               [smallint]  not null ,
[DAY_OF_MONTH]              [smallint]  not null ,
[DAY_OF_WEEK]               [tinyint]   not null ,

[YEAR_NAME]             [varchar] (4)   not null ,
[YEAR_QUARTER_NAME]         [varchar] (7)   not null ,
[YEAR_MONTH_NAME]           [varchar] (8)   not null ,
[YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG]          [varchar] (14)  not null ,
[QUARTER_NAME]              [varchar] (2)   not null ,
[MONTH_NAME]                [varchar] (3)   not null ,
[MONTH_NAME_LONG]           [varchar] (9)   not null ,
[WEEKDAY_NAME]              [varchar] (3)   not null ,
[WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG]         [varchar] (9)   not null ,

[START_OF_YEAR_DATE]            [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_YEAR_DATE]          [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_QUARTER_DATE]         [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_QUARTER_DATE]           [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_MONTH_DATE]           [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_MONTH_DATE]         [datetime]  not null ,

[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
[START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
[END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,

[QUARTER_SEQ_NO]            [int]       not null ,
[MONTH_SEQ_NO]              [int]       not null ,

[WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
[WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,

[JULIAN_DATE]               [int]       not null ,
[MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE]          [int]       not null ,

[ISO_DATE]              [varchar](10)   not null ,
[ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO]          [int]       not null ,
[ISO_WEEK_NO]               [smallint]  not null ,
[ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK]           [tinyint]   not null ,
[ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME]            [varchar](8)    not null ,
[ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME]    [varchar](10)   not null ,

[DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD]        [varchar](10)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D]          [varchar](10)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY]        [varchar](10)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY]          [varchar](10)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY]        [varchar](12)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY]      [varchar](18)   not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY]          [varchar](8)    not null ,
[DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY]            [varchar](8)    not null 
) 
as
begin
declare @cr         varchar(2)
select @cr          = char(13)+Char(10)
declare @ErrorMessage       varchar(400)
declare @START_DATE     datetime
declare @END_DATE       datetime
declare @LOW_DATE   datetime

declare @start_no   int
declare @end_no int

-- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not null 
if @FIRST_DATE is null
    begin
    select @ErrorMessage =
        '@FIRST_DATE cannot be null'
    goto Error_Exit
    end

-- Verify @LAST_DATE is not null 
if @LAST_DATE is null
    begin
    select @ErrorMessage =
        '@LAST_DATE cannot be null'
    goto Error_Exit
    end

-- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not before 1754-01-01
IF  @FIRST_DATE < '17540101'    begin
    select @ErrorMessage =
        '@FIRST_DATE cannot before 1754-01-01'+
        ', @FIRST_DATE = '+
        isnull(convert(varchar(40),@FIRST_DATE,121),'NULL')
    goto Error_Exit
    end

-- Verify @LAST_DATE is not after 9997-12-31
IF  @LAST_DATE > '99971231' begin
    select @ErrorMessage =
        '@LAST_DATE cannot be after 9997-12-31'+
        ', @LAST_DATE = '+
        isnull(convert(varchar(40),@LAST_DATE,121),'NULL')
    goto Error_Exit
    end

-- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not after @LAST_DATE
if @FIRST_DATE > @LAST_DATE
    begin
    select @ErrorMessage =
        '@FIRST_DATE cannot be after @LAST_DATE'+
        ', @FIRST_DATE = '+
        isnull(convert(varchar(40),@FIRST_DATE,121),'NULL')+
        ', @LAST_DATE = '+
        isnull(convert(varchar(40),@LAST_DATE,121),'NULL')
    goto Error_Exit
    end

-- Set @START_DATE = @FIRST_DATE at midnight
select @START_DATE  = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@FIRST_DATE),0)
-- Set @END_DATE = @LAST_DATE at midnight
select @END_DATE    = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@LAST_DATE),0)
-- Set @LOW_DATE = earliest possible SQL Server datetime
select @LOW_DATE    = convert(datetime,'17530101')

-- Find the number of day from 1753-01-01 to @START_DATE and @END_DATE
select  @start_no   = datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,@START_DATE) ,
    @end_no = datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,@END_DATE)

-- Declare number tables
declare @num1 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)
declare @num2 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)
declare @num3 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)

-- Declare table of ISO Week ranges
declare @ISO_WEEK table
(
[ISO_WEEK_YEAR]         int     not null
    primary key clustered,
[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE]  datetime    not null,
[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]    Datetime    not null
)

-- Find rows needed in number tables
declare @rows_needed        int
declare @rows_needed_root   int
select  @rows_needed        = @end_no - @start_no + 1
select  @rows_needed        =
        case
        when @rows_needed < 10
        then 10
        else @rows_needed
        end
select  @rows_needed_root   = convert(int,ceiling(sqrt(@rows_needed)))

-- Load number 0 to 16
insert into @num1 (NUMBER)
select NUMBER = 0 union all select  1 union all select  2 union all
select          3 union all select  4 union all select  5 union all
select          6 union all select  7 union all select  8 union all
select          9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
select         12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
select         15
order by
    1
-- Load table with numbers zero thru square root of the number of rows needed +1
insert into @num2 (NUMBER)
select
    NUMBER = a.NUMBER+(16*b.NUMBER)+(256*c.NUMBER)
from
    @num1 a cross join @num1 b cross join @num1 c
where
    a.NUMBER+(16*b.NUMBER)+(256*c.NUMBER) <
    @rows_needed_root
order by
    1

-- Load table with the number of rows needed for the date range
insert into @num3 (NUMBER)
select
    NUMBER = a.NUMBER+(@rows_needed_root*b.NUMBER)
from
    @num2 a
    cross join
    @num2 b
where
    a.NUMBER+(@rows_needed_root*b.NUMBER) < @rows_needed
order by
    1

declare @iso_start_year int
declare @iso_end_year   int

select  @iso_start_year = datepart(year,dateadd(year,-1,@start_date))
select  @iso_end_year   = datepart(year,dateadd(year,1,@end_date))

-- Load table with start and end dates for ISO week years
insert into @ISO_WEEK
    (
    [ISO_WEEK_YEAR],
    [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],
    [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]
    )
select
    [ISO_WEEK_YEAR] = a.NUMBER,
    [0ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE] =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,
        dateadd(day,3,dateadd(year,a.[NUMBER]-1900,0))
        )/7)*7,@LOW_DATE),
    [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]    =
        dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,
        dateadd(day,3,dateadd(year,a.[NUMBER]+1-1900,0))
        )/7)*7,@LOW_DATE))
from
    (
    select
        NUMBER = NUMBER+@iso_start_year
    from
        @num3
    where
        NUMBER+@iso_start_year <= @iso_end_year
    ) a
order by
    a.NUMBER

-- Load Date table
insert into @DATE
select
    [DATE_ID]           = a.[DATE_ID] ,
    [DATE]              = a.[DATE] ,

    [NEXT_DAY_DATE]         =
        dateadd(day,1,a.[DATE]) ,

    [YEAR]          =
        datepart(year,a.[DATE]) ,
    [YEAR_QUARTER]      =
        (10*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+datepart(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,

    [YEAR_MONTH]        =
        (100*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+datepart(month,a.[DATE]) ,
    [YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR]      =
        (1000*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+
        datediff(dd,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,a.[DATE]),0),a.[DATE])+1 ,
    [QUARTER]       =
        datepart(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
    [MONTH]     =
        datepart(month,a.[DATE]) ,
    [DAY_OF_YEAR]           =
        datediff(dd,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,a.[DATE]),0),a.[DATE])+1 ,
    [DAY_OF_MONTH]          =
        datepart(day,a.[DATE]) ,
    [DAY_OF_WEEK]       =
        -- Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ,,,Saturday = 7
        (datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])%7)+1  ,
    [YEAR_NAME]     =
        datename(year,a.[DATE]) ,
    [YEAR_QUARTER_NAME] =
        datename(year,a.[DATE])+' Q'+datename(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
    [YEAR_MONTH_NAME]   =
        datename(year,a.[DATE])+' '+left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3) ,
    [YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG]  =
        datename(year,a.[DATE])+' '+datename(month,a.[DATE]) ,
    [QUARTER_NAME]      =
        'Q'+datename(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
    [MONTH_NAME]        =
        left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3) ,
    [MONTH_NAME_LONG]   =
        datename(month,a.[DATE]) ,
    [WEEKDAY_NAME]      =
        left(datename(weekday,a.[DATE]),3) ,
    [WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG] =
        datename(weekday,a.[DATE]),

    [START_OF_YEAR_DATE]    =
        dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
    [END_OF_YEAR_DATE]  =
        dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)) ,

    [START_OF_QUARTER_DATE] =
        dateadd(quarter,datediff(quarter,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
    [END_OF_QUARTER_DATE]   =
        dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(quarter,datediff(quarter,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)) ,

    [START_OF_MONTH_DATE]   =
        dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
    [END_OF_MONTH_DATE] =
        dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530107'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530107'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530101'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530101'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530102'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530102'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530103'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530103'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530104'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530104'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530105'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530105'),

    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]   =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530106'),
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]     =
        dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530106'),

    [QUARTER_SEQ_NO]            = 
        datediff(quarter,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE]),
    [MONTH_SEQ_NO]              =
        datediff(month,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE]),

    [WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7,
    [WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO]      =
        datediff(day,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7,

    [JULIAN_DATE]           =
        datediff(day,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])+2361331,
    [MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE]      =
        datediff(day,'18581117',a.[DATE]),
--/*

    [ISO_DATE]      =
        replace(convert(char(10),a.[DATE],111),'/','-') ,

    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO]      =
        (100*b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+
        (datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1 ,

    [ISO_WEEK_NO]       =
        (datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1 ,

    [ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK]       =
        -- Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ,,,Saturday = 7
        (datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])%7)+1  ,

    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME]        =
        convert(varchar(4),b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+'-W'+
        right('00'+convert(varchar(2),(datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1),2) ,

    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME]        =
        convert(varchar(4),b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+'-W'+
        right('00'+convert(varchar(2),(datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1),2) +
        '-'+convert(varchar(1),(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])%7)+1) ,
--*/
    [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD]        =
        convert(char(10),a.[DATE],111) ,
    [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D]      = 
        convert(varchar(10),
        convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))),
    [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY]        = 
        convert(char(10),a.[DATE],101) ,
    [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY]      = 
        convert(varchar(10),
        convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
    [DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY]        = 
        convert(varchar(12),
        left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3)+' '+
        convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+', '+
        convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
    [DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY]  = 
        convert(varchar(18),
        datename(month,a.[DATE])+' '+
        convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+', '+
        convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
    [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY]      =
        convert(char(8),a.[DATE],1) ,
    [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY]        = 
        convert(varchar(8),
        convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
        right(convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE])),2))
from
    (
    -- Derived table is all dates needed for date range
    select  top 100 percent
        [DATE_ID]   = aa.[NUMBER],
        [DATE]      =
            dateadd(dd,aa.[NUMBER],@LOW_DATE)
    from
        (
        select
            NUMBER = NUMBER+@start_no 
        from
            @num3
        where
            NUMBER+@start_no <= @end_no
        ) aa
    order by
        aa.[NUMBER]
    ) a
    join
    -- Match each date to the proper ISO week year
    @ISO_WEEK b
    on a.[DATE] between 
        b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE] and 
        b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]
order by
    a.[DATE_ID]

return

Error_Exit:

-- Return a pesudo error message by trying to
-- convert an error message string to an int.
-- This method is used because the error displays
-- the string it was trying to convert, and so the
-- calling application sees a formatted error message.

declare @error int

set @error = convert(int,@cr+@cr+
'*******************************************************************'+@cr+
'* Error in function F_TABLE_DATE:'+@cr+'* '+
isnull(@ErrorMessage,'Unknown Error')+@cr+
'*******************************************************************'+@cr+@cr)

return

end



GO
```

Comment: I think this is probably the original article you got it from: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519

Comment: Yeah looks like it, was many years ago. Best date function I have ever found

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select convert(date, '2012-01-31', 102) lastdate
 union all
 select dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,(dateadd(d,1,lastdate))))
 from cte where lastdate < '2012-12-31')
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Numbers table(*), it's just:

```
select DATEADD(month,n,'20120131') from Numbers where n between 0 and all
```

Basically, `DATEADD(month,...` will automatically clip the day portion of its result to the last day of the month, if necessary. So, provided you're always adding months to a date that's on the 31st, it will produce the desired result.

---

(*) if you don't, just add a CTE before the query:

```
;with Numbers (n) as (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11
)
select DATEADD(month,n,'20120131') from Numbers
```